# How to reverse the order of input and echoed input in an Android Studio 3.1.2 "Live template"?

Tags: android-studio, live-templates

I'm in Android Studio 3.1.2's `File` , `Settings...` , `Editor` , `Live templates` creating a new template named `lgg` to aid with debugging my problems with `Context`:

```
    Log.w("", "<" + $VAR2$ + "> is value of [$VAR2$]");
```

Note that `$VAR2$` occurs in two places. When I type `lgg` and hit tab, the cursor is positioned at the first `$VAR2$` spot, like so:

`Log.w("", "<" +`
**[]** 
`+ "> is the value of [`
`] ")`

As I type, for example, **mContext**, the second `$VAR2$` spot echoes what I type, like so:

`Log.w("", "<" +` 
**mCo** 
`+ "> is the value of [`
**mCo**
`] ")`

Great! During execution, stuff like this is output (after I finish typing **mContext**, and other similar lines):

```
    <com.dslomer64.sqhell.MainActivity@ca3e6b0> is the value of [mContext] 
    <android.view.ContextThemeWrapper@e330929> is the value of [builder.getContext()] 
    <android.app.AlertDialog$Builder@73b94ae> is value of [builder]  
    <android.widget.TextView{7c6ce5b V.ED..... ......ID 0,0-0,0}> is the value of [message]
```

I'd rather have the name of the object precede the value instead of value preceding object name. I'd rather have this as debugging output...

```
    The value of [mContext] is <com.dslomer64.sqhell.MainActivity@ca3e6b0>
```

But in order to get the object name displayed first, it has to be inside double quotes. That is, the template would have to be ...

```
Log.w("", "The value of [$VAR2$] is [" + $VAR2$ + "]")
```

... in order to translate into ...

```
Log.w("", "The value of [mContext] is <" + mContext +">");
```

... to make the output become ...

`The value of [mContext] is <com.whoever.whatever.MainActivity@ca3e6b0>`

But then autocomplete is impossible.

So.

What would that template have to look like in order for the cursor to be placed *here* at the *second* `$VAR2$` ...

`Log.w("", "<" +`
`+ "> is the value of [`
**[]** 
`] ")`

... with the echoing of typing occurring in the *first* `$VAR2$`?